# What is the best way to add Monetag's ads (PropellerAds) to a NextJs app

Tags: next.js

I have a website developed on top of NextJs app. I am now trying to add PropellerAds (Monetag) javascript codes on my website. It throws errors `Error: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}` when I added the provided script from Monetag on the website.

```
<script>(function(a,b,c,d){a.src=b,s.setAttribute('data-zone',c),d.appendChild(a);})(document.createElement('script'),'https://inklinkor.com/tag.min.js',1234567,document.body||document.documentElement)</script>
```

Please let me know if you guys have a solution for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the solution. For those who are also struggling with the same issue, just add the following scripts in _document.js under the opening `<body>` tag.

```
<body>
   <script
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
         __html: `(function(a,b,c,d){a.src=b,s.setAttribute('data-zone',c),d.appendChild(a);})(document.createElement('script'),'https://inklinkor.com/tag.min.js',1234567,document.body||document.documentElement)`,
      }}
   />
```